# Google analytics is showing Internet explorer 7 for following user agent. Why?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics, internet-explorer-7, user-agent

I am trying to nail down issues reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312678/google-analytics-reports-a-high-amount-of-internet-explorer-7-traffic).

I created a "session scope", custom dimension to send "user agent" to Google Analytics.

Now, when I observe, I see, Google analytics is showing "Internet explorer 7" for following user agent

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) like Gecko

For me, msie7 is not present as well, trident and rv:11.0 means it is IE11.

What I am missing here? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Images from Google Analytics dashboard

[image: Images from Google Analytics dashboard]

Comment: f12>Emulation tab of dev tools (in IE11) will tell you which IE emulation mode your domain/page is using and how it was established.... eg. meta/header x-ua, Enterprise Site Mode lists, user Compatibility View List. or you can type about:compat in the IE address bar to list your IE browsers summary of compatibility view settings and search for your domain/page.

Comment: Thanks @RobParsons. My question is more like why given user agent is flagged as IE7 by Google Analytics engine. More like, how Google Analytics define the browser version logic.

Comment: There are two userAgent strings in IE... 1 is the request header userAgent value, the other is navigator.userAgent value..... They may differ, depending on the Emulation mode (set by Enterprise site mode lists or x-ua settings). google analytics uses the request header value. f12>Network tab, click the start button to record request and responses...double click an item to inspect its header. f12>Console tab, type navaigator.userAgent to return its value. f12>Emulation tab, tells you which IE emulation mode is used and how it was established.